# How to make multiple list from one list in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, list-manipulation

I want to make the multiple list from one list on condition base.

Actual data:

```
numbers = [1, 2, 3,4,5,6,7,8,9, 1, 11, 12, 13, 1, 21, 22, 25, 6, 1, 34 ,5 ,6 ,7,78]
```

Expected outcome:

```
[1, 2, 3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
[1, 11, 12, 13]
[1, 21, 22, 25, 6]
[1, 34 ,5 ,6 ,7,78]
```

Here is my attempt:

```
list_number=[]
numbers = [1, 2, 3,4,5,6,7,8,9, 1, 11, 12, 13, 1, 21, 22, 25, 6, 1, 34 ,5 ,6 ,7,78]
for x in numbers:
    if x==1:
        list_number.append(numbers)

print list_number[0]
```

Comment: post your attempts..

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: Is `1` a separator, or is there some other logic at work?

Comment: ' list_number=[]
numbers = [1, 2, 3,4,5,6,7,8,9, 1, 11, 12, 13, 1, 21, 22, 25, 6, 1, 34 ,5 ,6 ,7,78]
for x in numbers:
    if x==1:
        list_number.append(numbers)

print list_number[0] '

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 1 is a separator and I am supposed to creates new list when it start from 1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rather than adding new references/copies of the original `numbers` to the `list`, either start a new `list` whenever you see a `1` or add to the latest one otherwise:

```
list_number = []
numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 11, 12, 13, 1, 21, 22, 25, 6, 1, 34, 5, 6, 7, 78]
for x in numbers:
    if x==1:
        list_number.append([1])
    else:
        list_number[-1].append(x)

print list_number
```

Result:

```
>>> for x in list_number:
...     print x
...
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
[1, 11, 12, 13]
[1, 21, 22, 25, 6]
[1, 34, 5, 6, 7, 78]
```

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is a 2 stepper, first find the indices of the ones, then print from one to the other and from the last to the end:

```
 ones_index=[]
 numbers = [1, 2, 3,4,5,6,7,8,9, 1, 11, 12, 13, 1, 21, 22, 25, 6, 1, 34 ,5 ,6 ,7,78]
 for i,x in enumerate(numbers):
     if x==1:
         ones_index.append(i)

for i1,i in enumerate(ones_index):
     try:
         print numbers[i:ones_index[i1+1]]
    except:
         print numbers[i:]
```